# For each Loop but Without Looping in Message Box

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, msgbox

Below code simply states that for my range, if it contains a value of 1 (or 100%) or greater then highlight it in red.

But I want to know respond (in case conditional is met) a message box without having to go through the next procedure, which will pop the message box as many times as there are red cells (for how many cells meet the condition x >= 1)

Is there a way to do this, to have just one message box pop up if condition is met; if condition is not met, another message box will pop up, like MsgBox("good to process")

I've tried looping out the message box but doesn't appear to work

```
 Sub myCode()

    Dim iRow As Range, cell As Range

    Set iRow = Range("J16:M43")

    For Each cell In iRow

        If cell.Value >= 1 Then            'message box here will repeat

            cell.Interior.Color = 255

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: When should the MsgBox appear then and what should the message be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you need to set a variable to 'remember' if the condition is met.

```
Sub myCode()
    Dim iRow As Range, cell As Range, conditionMet as Boolean
    conditionMet=False
    Set iRow = Range("J16:M43")
    For Each cell In iRow
        If cell.Value >= 1 Then            
            cell.Interior.Color = 255
            conditionMet = True
        End If
    Next
    If conditionMet Then
        'Message for condition met
    Else 
        'Message for condition not met
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Once condition is met, use `Exit For`. There no point in continuing the loop

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't work if you still wanted all the cells to be highlighted.

Comment: Thank you both! I would like all the cells to be highlighted in my case